# SQLite Compare Two Tables with Different Schema

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

I am working on a typical problem where I need to compare TWO tables with different schema for data differences.

```
Name: Table_A
Date          Product     Price      Quantity        
_______     __________   _______     ________
5/9/2016        1          103.2      15000
6/9/2016        2          80.15      13000
7/9/2016        3          14.50      50000
8/9/2016        3          15.50      35000
```

The Second Table is as follows:

```
Name: Table_B
TimeStamp            Product       Price         Quantity
_________________    __________   _______        ________
20/9/2016 10:00am        1         106.00         20000
21/9/2016 10:10am        2         83.15          30000
25/9/2016 10:10am        2         83.15          50000
22/9/2016 10:30am        3         17.50          40000
23/9/2016 10:30am        3         19.50          60000
```

Let say Table B Product 3's price on 23/9/2016 is higher than Table A Product 3's price on 8/9/2016. What would be the SQL statement to compare the Price and Quantity in Ascending or Descending Order between two Tables?

I think we should use the INNER JOIN but I just got stuck. I have to sort out the dates from the Tables first and then able to pinpoint the Product in order to make a comparison on the Price.

I tried to write something like these but it is totally off course.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('Cable.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Product as product, Price FROM Table_A  INNER JOIN "
   "(SELECT Product as product, max(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp, Price 
   from Table_B WHERE TimeStamp ) ............)"

data = cur.fetchall()
counter = 0

for rows in data:
     print(rows)
     counter += 1

print(counter)
```

I just want to make the comparison works.

Thanks in advance. 
Hank

Comment: Why don't you synchronise the shemas?

Comment: If I understand right, you can just make a union with your desired columns (Product, Price, Quantity) and order as desired

Comment: What do you mean with "compare"? Show the desired output for the example data.

Comment: The desire output for the example data is as follows:    Timestamp 23/9/2016 10:30am        Product 3         Price 19.50